Importing Data from one Google Sheet to another using Dropdowns
I am using Google Sheets for a Dungeons and Dragons campaign to help me track initiative order. I have in another sheet data for monsters and other creatures (like health, armor class, stats, etc) and within the initiative sheet I use dropdowns to assign tokens (for tracking locations on a map), names, and the actual initiative order number.
Since I have the stat blocks on the initiative tracker so that I am not going back and forth, instead of manually importing every stat each time I create an encounter, I would like to be able to select the creature from a dropdown list and have it automatically import the statistics I have in another sheet into the initiative tracker sheet, but after researching I can not find the appropriate way of doing it. Any help would be appreciative.
I have fooled around with the import functions but can not find anything that seems to connect to the dropdown options.

I would like to be able to select the creature from a dropdown list and have it automatically import the statistics I have in another sheet into the initiative tracker sheet, Would you please provide sample data for both sheets and an example of the expected outcome. Would you please advise whether the imported data would become "out-of-date" at any stage, and would need to be updated. It sounds as though a script might would be required (in order to trigger the data import). Have you considered this, and how one or all validation rule(s) would be updated)?
